# AEM Link Checker: How to prevent the Link is removed if it is INVALID

Tags: aem

I have a request from PM to prevent AEM automatically removing the invalid link in Publisher.

Here are from [AEM Document](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/administering/operations/external-link-checker.html?lang=en) :

> Internal links are validated as soon as the content author adds an internal links to a page. If the link becomes invalid:
>
> - It is removed from the publisher. The text of the link remains, but
>   the link itself is removed.
> - It is shown as a broken link in the
>   authoring interface.

I tried with many settings but it didn't work for me. Anyone knows the anwser?

I really appreciate your help.

Thank,
Duc

Answer (score 0):

- You can add x-cq-linkchecker="valid" attribute in the  tag to make sure that links are always mark as valid by AEM. In this case link checker will check the link but will mark it valid. ( For Ex:- <a x-cq-linkchecker=”valid” …>)
- You can optionally use x-cq-linkchecker="skip" attribute in the  tag as well. In this case link checker will not even check for validity for link. ( For Ex:- <a x-cq-linkchecker=”skip” …>)

Comment: We know this way and tested it. What I meant here is to disable via Setting instead of adding this attribute for Link Tag. 
Thanks,